# Toggle only the current div after you click its own toggle button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML structure:

(jade template language)

```
#review-item-1.review-item
      a.submit-review-toggle(href="#").review-item-toggle +
      h3 Service
      .review-overview
        textarea(class='submit-review-overview', name='message', placeholder='Overview')
      .review-photo
        img(src="images/no-photo.png")
```

I want to be able to expand and collapse the height of the `.review-item div` (at the top):

```
$(".submit-review-toggle").click(function() {
    $(".review-item").animate({
        height: "toggle",
    }, "slow");
});
```

The problem is that I will have a lot of `.review-item` divs in a single page. So I need to just toggle the 'current' `.review-item` div after you click its own `.submit-review-toggle` button.

Any suggestions of how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you post a clearer (i.e. true HTML) structure? If you only need to get the parent of an element, jQuery has the parent() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(".submit-review-toggle").click(function() {
   $(this).closest(".review-item").animate({
       height: "toggle",
   }, "slow");
```

});

The closest selector gets the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree. [See here for documentation](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Comment: so that's the same as saying: toggle its parent with that class?

Comment: Well, ".closest()" means, "find the nearest parent that matches the following selector".